# Hyper-V Reporting Wrong Uptime

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012

I am having an issue whereby Hyper-V Manager does not report the correct uptime for some of our Virtual Machines.

I had started all the Virtual machines minutes apart but on the Hyper-V Manager there are a few which report different uptime.

```
Two Domain Controllers - 7 Days
Exchange - 5 Days 5 hours
SQL Server - 5 Days 9 hours
DATA Server - 4 Days 13 hours
```

So far I have already done the following:

- Checked through Event Logs for any errors or resets. (e.g Hyper-V Worker)
- **net stats srv**  - on each virtual machine which reports the same uptime as the DCs
- Using **systeminfo | find /i "boot time"** - which again reports same uptime as DCs
- **Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime**

All of the above commands give me the same uptime as the Domain Controllers but HyperV is reporting the wrong uptime.

Only thing we have running is backups but these do not **save** or **reset** the virtual machine as this is known to cause the uptime reported to be wrong.

Does any one have any other suggestions to what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked the NTP settings on the servers? Perhaps there is an issue with the time syncing.

Comment: All servers times are identical no mismatch at all.

Comment: What are the results of running `w32tm /query /source` from an admin terminal?

Comment: A list of uk.pool.ntp.org servers in the uk!

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found my issue.

We currently using Veeam to run backups on each Virtual machine. I decided to watch the backups run naturally at 2am.

I noticed within the Hyper-V Manager window when the Backup started on a particular VM the **Uptime** had paused while Veeam backup was being carried out. There is no save or reset logs when the backup has started.

All of the other virtual machines times were still ticking away.

It looks like my Veeam Backups are the culprit.. although I would have expected a reset or save log in Event Viewer!

Answer (score 0):

Its not only of the Veeam, the same thing happens with DPM 2012 R2 on Hyper-V 2012 R2 that i'm running, is because it takes save state backup so it "closes" the uptime when will complete the backup and starts the uptime from 0:0:01.

If you go inside of the Windows VM navigate to Task Manager -> Performance -> Check CPU, then you will see it correct or if it is linux vm run the uptime command.

Regards,

ankso

Comment: ankso, what you described above is not what i'm getting. That's what I expected to get. When a backup runs the uptime **freezes** and once the backup completes it continues from where it was frozen. The counter does not reset